# Switching back to parent window and performing action on parent throws JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, selenium

**Trying to automate an eCommerce website, SnapDeal**

I am getting this error in the console:

[image]

While switching from child window to parent window and trying some operations back on parent window.

```
    //Logging in to SnapDeal using Facebook.

    SnapDeal.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='fbUserLogin']")).click();
    String pWindow = SnapDeal.getWindowHandle();
    for (String winHandle : SnapDeal.getWindowHandles()) 
    {
           //Switch to child window 
           SnapDeal.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }

    WebElement FBLoginID = SnapDeal.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']"));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)SnapDeal;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='YourEmailID';", FBLoginID);

    WebElement FBPass = SnapDeal.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pass']"));
    JavascriptExecutor jE = (JavascriptExecutor)SnapDeal;
    jE.executeScript("arguments[0].value='YourPassword';", FBPass);
    SnapDeal.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='loginbutton']")).click();
    SnapDeal.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='__CONFIRM__']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    //Switching back to parent window
    SnapDeal.switchTo().window(pWindow);

    //logging out of the application in the parent window post switching 
    WebElement WelCome = SnapDeal.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Welcome')]"));
    WebElement LogOut = SnapDeal.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Logout')]"));
    Actions mousehover = new Actions(SnapDeal);
    mousehover.moveToElement(WelCome).perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    mousehover.click(LogOut).perform();
```

Any help in resolving this issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is possibly accessing an object which is no longer attached to DOM; which line throws this error?

Comment: What error your are getting?

Comment: @kushal : Error is thrown on switching back to parent window
and doing some operations on it. Code Snippet is already provided above.

Comment: @Shailendra : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUxiy.png

Comment: @Dannie: This line `String pWindow = SnapDeal.getWindowHandle();` should be executed before you have clicked the `fbLogin` button.

Comment: @kushal : Have tried your comment on the script, Still no luck. I am unable to perform any action [Say for e.g. I want to logout back] on the parent window after switching back.

Comment: What error do u face?

Answer (score 0):

use SET to first store the parent and child windows and then iterate it.I haven't tried your code, but this logic of using SET and iterator must work for you.